# Сравнение двух переменных типа string С++

Tags: c++

Есть две переменные типа `string`.

Нужно сравнить слова, и вывести уникальные.

Я читаю первую строку до пробела, чтобы вырезать слово, и сравнить её со второй строкой. Но как реализовать?

```
int main() {
    string s1, s2,t;
    stringstream gg;
    ifstream fin("input.txt");
    cout << "Vvedite vhodnuyu stroku"<<endl;
    getline(cin,s2);
    if (fin.is_open())
    {
        while (!fin.eof())
        {
            getline(fin,s1);
            for (int i = 0; s1[i]; i++)
            {
                if(s1[i] != ' ')
                {

                }
            }
        }
    }
    fin.close();
    system("pause");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string s1;    
stringstream gg;
map<string, int> m;
if (fin.is_open() {
    while (getline(fin, s1))
        gg << s1;
    while (gg >> s1)
        ++m[s1];
    for (const auto& p : m) {
        static int k = 0;
        if(++k == 10)
            cout << '\n';
        if(p.second == 1)
            cout << p.first <<' ';
    }
}
```